# How to keep two bash terminals session alive in python script?

Tags: python, bash, stdin, popen

I want to automate some process which will run some python scripts. I need to perform below steps

> - Step 1: Open bash terminal (terminal_1) and run "Source script1.sh" => If this script successfully executed, then step 2
> - Step 2: Run the another script "python script2.py" in the same bash terminal (terminal_1) => if this script is successfully run, then step 3
> - Step 3: Open another bash terminal (terminal_2) and run "python script3.py" => if this script is successful, then step 4
> - Step 4: Run another script "python script4.py" in the same terminal (terminal_2) => If this script successful. then, step 5
> - Step 5: Run final script "python script5.py" in the first terminal (terminal_1 and I need to keep the session of first terminal.), if successful the end the script.

This is my requirement. So I have searched some methods to do this process using python script. I am using windows environment with Cygwin.

**Method 1:**

Using

```
subprocess.Popen(["bash"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and read the output values using `Thread` and `stdout.readline()`

**Method 2:**

Using `pexpect.spawn` in python

**Method 3:**

Run first script and write to file => check successful then run another script. it will take more time.

I would like to know which method is suitable for my requirements. One problem here is to keep two bash terminal alive. Also please suggest if any other way is suitable here. Some examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: `pexpect` is generally the best way to automate interactive terminals. With `Popen()` it will be difficult to tell when a particular script is done in a particular terminal.

Comment: Because each invocation is of a separate subprocess, you have no reason for it to be the same parent shell. You can have each terminal run something like an IPC client that takes JSON or pexpect objects or what-have-you instead of running a real shell at all, and have that client run the various final scripts; that way you completely evade all the hard problems (like trying to disambiguate between a program you ran writing shell-like output vs _really_ being back at a shell).

Comment: (BTW, it's helpful to keep your mental model straight: there's no such thing as a "bash terminal"; a terminal is separate and independent of the software running inside it, and that _includes_ dependent of the shell, if any, that it kicks off as a client process; you can replace that shell with anything you want, including something that just interacts with a network stream)

Comment: that said, there isn't really a single Right Way we can offer here, so I'm not sure this is a good Stack Overflow question; there are plenty of comparably-reasonable approaches, and which one is "best" is going to depend on implementation details that only you are really privy to. (Personally, I would stay away from pexpect here if you need real terminals; it has things it's great for, but I don't see how this is one of them).

Comment: (btw, is this a native-Windows Python interpreter running Cygwin subprocesses, or a Cygwin-built Python interpreter? -- in the former case you have more options wrt. various `subprocess` options that control how Windows spawns terminals for your subprocess; Windows is a place where the "terminal is separate from the program running inside it" assertion I made above is a little less true than it is for the rest of the world running on more reasonable operating systems).

Comment: Why do you need terminals? Do scripts interact?

Comment: @ Diego Torres Milano Those scripts will create "venv" and it required for running script. So that's why i need to keep the terminal open